# $\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\aleph_1\}$ and $A_\alpha\subseteq\alpha$. Prove existence of stationary $T$ such that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$ is finite.

Tags: set-theory

We have family of finite sets $\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\aleph_1\}$ such that $A_\alpha\subseteq\alpha$ for $\alpha<\aleph_1$. Prove that there exists set $T\in Stat_{\aleph_2}$ such that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$ is finite.

I should use Fodor Lemma here somehow. I tried to take set $B$ of ordinals with $\aleph_0$ cofinality and define regressive function $f(\alpha)=\sup A_\alpha$ (it is regressive) for $\alpha\in B$, but I do not see that stationary set resulting from such function is desired one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a "coding-free" alternative to Stefan's answer.

First, a quick fact:

> *Claim*. Suppose I partition $\omega_1$ into countably many pieces. Then (at least) one piece is stationary.

*Proof*: if $P_i$ is nonstationary for each $i\in\omega$, let $C_i$ be a club disjoint from $P_i$; then $\bigcap C_i$ is a club disjoint from all $P_i$s, so we can't have $\bigcup_{i\in\omega} P_i=\omega_1$. $\quad\Box$

From the claim, we now argue as follows:

Given $\{A_\alpha:\alpha\in\omega_1\}$ as above, let $P_i=\{\alpha:\vert A_\alpha\vert=i\}$. By the claim above, for some $i$ we have that $P_i$ is stationary. So fix such an $i$.

Now for $n<i$ let $g_n$ be the function, with domain $P_i$, given by: $g_n(\alpha)$ is the $n$th element of $A_\alpha$ (counting from least to greatest). Each $g_n$ is regressive, and so we can iterate Fodor's lemma to get a stationary $S\subseteq P_i$ on which each $g_n$ is constant. But this means exactly that $A_\alpha=A_\beta$ for each $\alpha,\beta\in S$.

Comment: (+1) You could also use Fodor's Lemma directly to fix $i$ on a stationary set.

Comment: @StefanMesken That's a bit of a nuke though.

Comment: Well, yes, but  you are using it $i$ times anyway so it seemed odd to complicate the proof to avoid the $i+1$st usage of Fodors Lemma, don't you think?

Comment: @StefanMesken Sure, but I think it's worthwhile to distinguish certain facts as particularly easy, even if they occur in a more sophisticated argument. The OP should be comfortable on an immediate level with the fact that we can't write $\omega_1$ as the union of countably many nonstationary sets before they are so comfortable with Fodor's lemma.

Answer (score 5):

I guess there are several ways to skin this cat but this one came to mind first: Write, for each $\alpha < \omega_1$, $$A_{\alpha} = \{x^{\alpha}_1 < \ldots < x^\alpha_{n_{\alpha}} \}$$
Let
$$
f \colon \omega_1 \to \omega_1, \alpha \mapsto \langle n_{\alpha} , \langle x^{\alpha}_1, \ldots , x^\alpha_{n_{\alpha}} \rangle \rangle,
$$
where $\langle . \rangle$ is the (nested) Gödel pairing function.

Let $S \subseteq \omega_1$ be the stationary set of infinite ordinals closed under the Gödel pairing function. $f \restriction S$ is regressive. Hence, by Fodor, there is some stationary $T \subseteq S$ and some $\beta$ such that $f \restriction T = T \times \{ \beta \}$. $\beta$ now codes a unique, finite set $A \subseteq \omega_1$ via the procedure above $(\dagger)$ and we obtain that $A_{\alpha} = A$ for all $\alpha \in T$. In particular $\bigcup_{\alpha \in T} A_{\alpha} = A$ is finite.

---

$(\dagger)$ There are unique $n < \omega$ and $x_1 < \ldots < x_n < \omega_1$ such that $\langle n, \langle x_1, \ldots, x_n \rangle \rangle = \beta$ and then $A = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$ is the set coded by $\beta$. We need to include $n$ in this coding because we need to know how often we nested the Gödel pairing function in the second coordinate. Otherwise different sequences of necessarily different lengths will get mapped to the same ordinal -- ruining our coding.

Comment: If you think this is a weird solution -- I agree. But still... it was the first that came to mind.

Comment: your $S$ appears only once : there is a typo at some point ;)

Comment: @Max Thanks for spotting that. I'll correct it immediately.

Comment: This is the obvious approach, I don't see why it is weird. It is a common technique, to code a lot of structure as an ordinal so Fodor's lemma does more than giving us "a common ordinal".

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I'm not sure that I've ever applied Fodor's Lemma to finite sets of ordinals before. Maybe that's why it looks weird to me. (My first instinct was that there must be a simpler way -- especially because less than a common value for $A_\alpha$ is required. But if this is the standard approach, great. I'll keep it in mind for future use.)

Comment: You can always just use Fodor's lemma many times if that feels more natural: Use it first to fix the number of elements of $A_\alpha$, then again to fix the minimum of $A_\alpha$, then the second component, and so on.

Comment: An example where this idea appears is in Laver's proof of $\omega_1\to(\omega_1,\omega+1)^2$, which actually establishes that either we get a *closed* set of type $\omega+1$ in the second color, or a stationary set in the first color.